# Allow more cpus with docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So with `docker info` I have "CPUs: 1" and in my docker-compose.yml I have `cpuset: "3"` as well as `cupset: "0"`.

This throws the following error when running the `docker-compose -p "name" up`: "ERROR: Requested CPUs are not available - requested 3, available: 0."

However, using the --cpuset="0-3" does not work and says that that option is not a part of docker-compose up.

How would I allow for more cpus for my containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way late, but I had a similar issue.

If you have only 1 CPU according to `docker info`, you can only have a `cpuset` option in docker-compose of 0. (The first CPU is 0). If your machine had 2 cores available, you would have access to CPU 0 and CPU 1. So you could use `cpuset: 0-1`.

My specific case had to do with docker-machine, which by default creates your virtual machine limited to 1 core.

Changing the create command to include
`--virtualbox-cpu-count 2` did the trick.